# Navigation using NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm making a game with 3 view controllers. I have tried using a UINavigationController to navigate between the views but it does not seem to be working.

I know this because the memory is retained after removing the previous view from the navigation stack and when returning to a previously instantiated view controller, the memory usage increases.

Here is the flow of the game:

Menu > Game > Game Over

At Game I want to remove the menu to minimize memory usage. I have tried the following with no success:

```
var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
viewControllers?.remove(at: 0)
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers!, animated: true)
```

At Game Over I want to remove Game if the player chooses to return to the menu, and instantiate a new menu view controller.

Comment: Does it take too much memory in your app, if it doesn't make the app crash or something, I think no need to worry.

Normally popViewController() will return the top view controller and remove the view controller from navigationController.

Comment: On previous models of the iPhone 5s, etc. it crashes. @MahmudAhsan

Comment: Does it mean, when user go from Menu -> Game -> Gamer Over it crashed in previous iPhone 5s?

Comment: When going through the process enough times, it crashes @MahmudAhsan

Comment: Well, as far as I remember, in one of my app what I did, At some point, I called, popToRootViewController() and then add a new View Controller to the navigation view Controller to solve some issues i mean, to remove the middle view controllers from navigationController.

And if you set animation: false, user can't recognize that.

Comment: You can try Setting GameVC as window